# matrix elements should not be greater than maximum value while getting updated during function call

Tags: python

I am using below fn:

```
def TABs4_tmp(x,ee,M,nrm1):  
    M += dot(sign(ee),sign(x.T))/nrm1 

ex:
      nrm1 is scalar= 2^10  
      ee is scalar= 1  
      x is an array of 100 elements
```

I am calling this function many times in my program and value of each element of M array(size 100) is getting updated each time.Currently elements of M could take any values, but I need element value's to be limited by some maximum value lets see 2.

Elements of M, those having values less than 2 can update to new value while calling this function, but Elements those are reached to maximum value 2, should not be updated.

I am new to Python , please help me to suggest any solution.

Comment: What do you mean by updating the elements of M? You are adding new elements to M by `M += dot(sign(ee),sign(x.T))/nrm1`

Comment: Yes.. you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
def TABs4_tmp(x,ee,M,nrm1): 
    temp = dot(sign(ee),sign(x.T))/nrm1 
    if temp<2:
        M += temp
```

Comment: temp would be an array, I think temp can't be compared with scalar value 2. I have tried this , gives me an error. any idea?

Comment: @user2486253: Do you want to add the elements of temp into M that are less than 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Numpy has functionality for exactly this.

They are called [MaskedArray](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.baseclass.htm)s.

```
import numpy.ma as ma

M = ma.MaskedAray(M)

def TABs4_tmp(x,ee,M,nrm1):
    M = ma.masked_greater(2,M)
    M += dot(sign(ee),sign(x.T))/nrm1
```

That should then only add to the unmasked parts.

Comment: I have tried above solution but it seems not working.  M_tmp=M;  def TABs4_tmp(x,ee,M,M_tmp,nrm1):  
    M = ma.masked_greater(M_tmp,1)  
    M = ma.masked_greater(M,-1)  
    M += dot(sign(ee),sign(x.T))/nrm1 '  
M is always getting zero. Not sure why?

Comment: Hi, This command masked the elements which is greater than the threshold. Do you have any idea if we can replace the masked value with the threshold value? Thanks.

Comment: Don't know if theres a proper way off the top of my head, you could try something like `M = M*M.mask + !M.mask*2`. Don't know if that will actually work though...